# How to convert webelement into List<Webelement> in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have webelement

```
WebElement element = driver.findelement(By.cssSelector("div#name"))
```

I want to convert WebElement element  into list

How can i convert it into list

I dont want to declare findelements again to get list. I need to reuse the webelement(element)

Comment: Why would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the line to below, where we are using `.findElements()` which will return a list of elements rather than `.findElement()`.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findelements(By.cssSelector("div#name"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use java.util.Collections.singletonList.

And your code can be so:

```
WebElement element = driver.findelement(By.cssSelector("div#name"));
List<WebElement> elements = java.util.Collections.singletonList(element );
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is a [statically typed](https://www.activestate.com/blog/python-vs-java-duck-typing-parsing-whitespace-and-other-cool-differences/), so to before putting the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) into the list, you have to create the list first and then add the *WebElement* within the list and you can use the following solution:

```
List<WebElement> elements = new ArrayList<>();
elements.add(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#name")));
```